# atk4 - simple apicli example

Tags: atk4

I'm trying to use Apicli to make a script that runs from command line.

This is my testing code (the script is in page/command)

```
include '../../atk4/loader.php'; 
$api=new ApiCLI('reportes');
$api->addLocation('atk4-addons',array(
         'php'=>array(
            'mvc',
            'misc/lib',
            )))->setParent($api->pathfinder->base_location);

$api->dbConnect();
$db = $this->api->db->dsql()   
       ->table('test t')
       ->do_getAssoc();
```

The output of this is

```
PHP Fatal error:  Uncaught exception 'ExceptionNotConfigured' with message 'You must  specify $config['dsn'] in your config.php' in /var/www/ossec/atk4/lib/ApiCLI.php:238
Stack trace:
#0 /var/www/ossec/atk4/lib/ApiCLI.php(276): ApiCLI->getConfig('dsn')
#1 /var/www/ossec/page/crons/reportes.php(13): ApiCLI->dbConnect()
#2 {main}
  thrown in /var/www/ossec/atk4/lib/ApiCLI.php on line 238
```

this do not reads config-default.php ? I've add

```
$config['dsn']='mysql://user:pass@localhost/test';
```

But it doesn't works.

Thanks all

Answer (score 1, accepted):

looking at ApiCli.php and seen the db definition, I've passed the parameters via the method

```
$api->dbConnect('mysql://user:pass@localhost/test');
```

And now It's working fine.

Regards
Alejandro

Answer (score 3):

You can solve the problem by changing current directory of cron execution.  Add these lines to the beginning of the file, which is executed by cron:

```
$_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'] = 'site_name'; 
$_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'] = '127.0.0.1'; 
$_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] = 'GET'; 
chdir('/home/user/...path_to_directory');
```

Comment: i'd suggest to use relative folder in "chdir".

Answer (score 0):

ApiCLI reads config-default then config.php file (code from ApiCLI), so it should pick your config file. Most probably it's looking in the wrong directory, as it checks the current directory:

```
function getConfig($path, $default_value = undefined){
    /**
     * For given path such as 'dsn' or 'logger/log_dir' returns
     * corresponding config value. Throws ExceptionNotConfigured if not set.
     */
    if(is_null($this->config)){
        $this->readConfig('config-default.php');
        $this->readConfig();
    }
    ......
}


function readConfig($file='config.php'){
    $orig_file = $file;
    if(is_null($this->config))$this->config=array();
    $config=array();
    if(strpos($file,'/')===false){
        $file=getcwd().'/'.$file;
        // ^^^^^^^
    }
    ...
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem, but the above solution didn't work, so used setConfig like this:

```
$config['dsn']='mysql://root@localhost/databasename';
$api=new ApiCLI();
$api->setConfig($config);
```